# Unable to deploy to Raspberry Pi from Visual Studio with error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

That's my setup:

[image]

- Debugger is started in Windows IoT.
- Firewall disabled
- Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25123.00 Update 2

I get an error:

```
DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2145615869
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same problem with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. This is a know issues per link below -

https://developer.windows.com/hu-hu/windows/holographic/known_issues

The work around suggests that restarting Visual Studio should resolve the problem but in my case problem persists even after restarting the Visual Studio. If you  attempt multiple times to deploy then sometimes you will be successful. I'll be uninstalling Visual Studio Update 2 which seems causing the problem.

Comment: The link might answer the question, but all of the important detail from the link, or an overview of the information needs to be in your answer

Comment: Will try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681470/windows-10-iot-core-arm-dep0001-unexpected-error-1988945906

Comment: @DarthVader The link lists all known issues how would it help if I copy and paste contents from there? Just typing DEP001 in google gives above link on the first page of search, I would argue what was need of this question if R2D2 had used google!

Comment: There seem to be multiple issues. As per R2D2's suggestion I tried the 10586.0.151029 image but it didn't help in my case. I tried to deploy the app from my second PC running exact same version of Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and.... I am able to successfully deploy the app. If I find an explanation I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Although the previous answer above might be correct I actually fixed it by:

1. Downloading this image:

   **10586.0.151029-1700.TH2_Release_IOTCoreRPi_armFRE.ISO**

instead of using the **IoT Dashboard** wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Open PowerShell as admin and run:

1. net start WinRM
2. Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value /machine-name or IP Address RPi/

Comment: Run this on the development machine, or on the RPi3?